# Compositional CollectionView Layout width constraint doesn't work

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uikit, autolayout

Following code is my compositional collectionview flow layout customization code for item and group. I want to calculate both height and width using auto layout but width constraint doesn't work. I didn't find any configuration for estimated width constraint in horizontal group.

```
let heightDimension = NSCollectionLayoutDimension.estimated(80)
let widthDimension = NSCollectionLayoutDimension.estimated(120)

let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
    widthDimension: widthDimension,
    heightDimension: heightDimension
)
let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)

// Group
let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
    widthDimension: widthDimension,
    heightDimension: heightDimension
)
let horizontalGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(
    layoutSize: groupSize,
    subitems: [item]
)
```